# Show a list of lint errors on bottom of sublime-text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, sublimelinter

I just got [sublime text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) and I'm installing [sublinter](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter3) and [eslint](https://github.com/roadhump/SublimeLinter-eslint). So the errors get shown on the actual line the errors at. How can I get it to show a list of all the errors of the current document on the bottom?

Here's what I mean. (This is an image from atom.)

[image]

Comment: Maybe the closest thing you can do is this, from http://sublimelinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/navigating.html: 
> At the bottom of the Sublime Text Tools menu, you will see a SublimeLinter submenu. Select SublimeLinter > Show All Errors. When you select the Show All Errors command, all errors in the view are displayed in a Quick Panel.

Comment: Can you please post a screen shot? (I already uninstalled eslint.)

Comment: btw which theme you are using for the lint error tooltip

Answer (score 3):

I personally tried to use SublimeLinter with SublimeLinter-contrib-tslint but it didn't navigate to the errors - it kept saying there are no lint errors even though I could see them on the screen in the individual files..

The closest I could get to what Atom provides (which I decided to move away because of the lagging scroll navigation) is this:

1) Choosing for example: Tools > Build System > TypeScript

2) Show Console (Ctrl+)

3) Tools > Build (Ctrl+B)

[image]